# Proper Formatting in a listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, formatting

I'm trying to format my listbox so that it looks neat when its in use.

I want to add dollar signs to my numbers, and left align them. Any help would be appreciated. They currently look really sloppy.

```
    Dim salesTotal As Double
    customerListBox.Items.Add("Customer: " & "                     " & "Total Sale: ")
    For Each record As DataRow In Me._442_Project_Part_2DataSet.Customers
        salesTotal += Double.Parse(CStr(record.Item("YTDSales")))
        customerListBox.Items.Add((CStr(record.Item("CustomerName"))) & "           " & (CStr(record.Item("YTDSales"))))
        customerListBox.Items.Add("------------------------------------------------")
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all ListBox arn't meant to be easily customizable.

To answer your question `I want to add dollar signs to my numbers, and left align them`, you need to use `String.PadLeft` function.

```
customerListBox.Items.Add((CStr(record.Item("CustomerName"))) & " : $" & (CStr(record.Item("YTDSales"))).PadLeft(8))
```

Note : I added 8 spaces in this exemple. It might vary depending on the numbers you have. I also added a colon and dollar sign between CustomerName and Sales.